# Is the appearance of Schur functions a coincidence?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, symmetric-groups, symmetric-functions, grassmannians, schur-functions

The [Schur functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_polynomial) are symmetric functions which appear in several different contexts:

1. The characters of the irreducible representations for the symmetric group (under the characteristic isometry).
2. The characters of the polynomial irreducible representations for the general linear group or unitary groups.
3. The cohomology classes of the Schubert cycles in the Grassmannian.
4. The images of the basis elements in the fermionic Fock space under the boson-fermion correspondence.
5. The orthonormal basis of the ring of symmetric functions with respect to a certain scalar product (satisfying certain desirable properties).

There are surely many more examples (that I would love to learn about!).

I know that the [Schur-Weyl duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Weyl_duality) relates the representation theory of the symmetric group with the representation theory of the general linear group, so these two can be related. There are also [several](https://arxiv.org/abs/0711.4079) [different](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0306414) [papers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0208107v2) addressing the relation of the Schubert calculus and the representations of the general linear group. I know less about the fermionic Fock space.

However, as far as I understand, many of these results hold only "in type A" and when their analogues are formulated for other types, different generalizations appear. For example, in the symplectic Schur-Weyl duality, the general linear group is replaced by the symplectic group, and the symmetric group is replaced by the [Brauer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brauer_group); but the characters of these two objects are no longer the same. Similarly, the connection between the cohomology ring of the Grassmannians in other Lie types seem to be different from the representation theory of the corresponding Lie objects.

**Question**: Is it a coincidence that the Schur functions appear in these independent contexts?

I want to understand the rigidity of the Schur functions in these examples when modified. For instance, the equivariant cohomology of the Grassmannian yields the factorial Schur functions. Are there analogous concepts in the representation theory of the general linear group? The representation theory of the super Lie algebra for the general linear group gives the supersymmetric Schur functions. Is there an analogue in the cohomology of the Grassmannian? Or is the appearance of Schur functions in these contexts coincidental, without any generalizations having a corresponding analogue?

Comment: While it is true that in other types the close connection between these various guises of Schur functions (irreducible representations of algebraic groups, Schubert classes, etc.) breaks down, I would assert that the appearance of Schur functions in all these places is not just "a coincidence." Possibly Allen Knutson will chime in explaining how the fundamental idea is the category $\mathrm{Rep}(\mathbf{Vect})$ or something like that...

Comment: The irreducible characters of the symmetric groups are not themselves Schur functions. Instead the Schur functions are their images under the characteristic isometry, and there is a close connection between the symmetric group characters and symmetric functions via the Murnaghan--Nakayama rule in the form $s_\lambda p_k = \sum_\mu \epsilon(\mu/\lambda) s_\mu$, where the sum is over skew-partitions of size $k$. This makes connection 1 a little less direct than your question might suggest.

Comment: I'd add also, in reference to 5, that there are, of course, infinitely many orthonormal bases of the ring of symmetric functions. Okay the Schur function basis is particularly nice/important, but for instance the scaled power sum functions $p_\lambda / z_\lambda$ are also orthonormal. In fact it's this basis that's used to define the characteristic isometry.

Comment: @MarkWildon: but $p_{\lambda}/z_{\lambda}$ is only defined over $\mathbb{Q}$; $s_{\lambda}$ being defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed a special feature.

Comment: Apparently (is this right?) the fact that the symmetric group is the Weyl group of the general linear group and that it appears in Schur-Weyl duality is just a coincidence. I found one such statement on pages 5-6 of https://math.columbia.edu/~samdehority/files/spring_2021_seminar_1/Jin-Cheng_Guu_talk_3-31-21_notes.pdf.

Comment: Over $\mathbb Z$, the Schur functions are the only monomial-positive homogeneous orthonormal basis with nonnegative structure coefficients.

Comment: I added too many hypotheses in my last comment. What I should have said is that they are the *only* monomial-positive orthonormal basis over $\mathbb Z$, and also the only one over $\mathbb Q$ that has nonnegative *integer* structure coefficients.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. How is the question "is it a coincidence?" different from the question "is it false in other types?"? Are you asking if there is a way to generalize Schur functions other than by considering other types? One can add parameters and get Macdonald polynomials, for example; does that count?

Comment: I want to understand the rigidity of the Schur functions in these examples when modified. For instance, the equivariant cohomology of the Grassmannian yields the factorial Schur functions. Are there analogous concepts in the representation theory of the general linear group? The representation theory of the super Lie algebra for the general linear group gives the supersymmetric Schur functions. Is there an analogue in the cohomology of the Grassmannian? Or is the appearance of Schur functions in these contexts coincidental, without any generalizations having a corresponding analogue?

Comment: As luck would have it, my undergraduate student, Antoine Labelle, just posted a paper which partially answers this question, https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.00855.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by Joel in the comments, I just posted this week on arxiv a paper that explains the relationship between some of these points using the geometric Satake correspondence ([arxiv.org/abs/2310.00855](https://arxiv.org/abs/2310.00855)).
The idea is to construct a ring isomorphism between $H^\bullet(G(n,m))$ and a suitable quotient of the ring of symmetric polynomials $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]^{S_n}$ which sends Schubert cycles to Schur polynomials by first constructing it as a representation isomorphism and then upgrading to an isomorphism of rings with bases. Moreover, this can be generalized in a straightforward way to the torus-equivariant setting, with double Schur polynomials (you can find the details of this in the paper). Let me explain roughly how this is done in the non-equivariant setting.

First, the boson-fermion correspondence usually concerns an isomorphism between the semi-infinite wedge space (or fermionic Fock space), which is a representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_\infty$ of $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$ matrices, with the algebra $\Lambda$ of symmetric functions in infinitely many variables. I will however discuss a variant of it involving an isomorphism between the $n^{th}$ wedge representation of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_\infty^+$ of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ matrices and the algebra of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables.

Define $\mathfrak{gl}_\infty^+$ to be the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$ matrices with finitely many nonzero diagonals. It acts naturally on any vector space with a basis indexed by $\mathbb{N}$, in particular on $\mathbb{C}[x]$ (using the basis $1,x,x^2,\ldots$). This induces an action on $\bigwedge^n \mathbb{C}[x]$, which we can identify with the vector space of skew-symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables, which I'll denote $\Lambda_n^\text{sgn}$. Moreover, multiplication by the Vandermonde determininant $\delta=\Pi_{i<j} (x_i-x_j)$ defines an isomorphism between the vector space of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables (which I'll denote $\Lambda_n$) and the skew-symmetric polynomials $\Lambda_n^\text{sgn}$.
The "finite $n$" boson-fermion correspondence is then simply the isomorphism
$$\bigwedge^n \mathbb{C}[x] = \Lambda_n^\text{sgn} \underset{\cdot \delta}{\overset{\sim}{\longleftarrow}}\Lambda_n$$
(the left hand side would be called by physicists the fermionic Fock space and the right hand side the bosonic Fock space).

Moreover, an important feature of this boson-fermion correspondence is that it is equivariant for the action of the Heisenberg subalgebra. I'll discuss only the action of the negative part of the Heisenberg subalgebra, which is the abelian subalgebra $\mathfrak{h}^-$ consisting of lower triangular matrices whose entries are constant on diagonals. Identifying $\mathfrak{gl}_\infty^+$ with its image inside $\text{End}_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{C}[x])$, these are exactly the "multiplication by $p$" operators for $p\in \mathbb{C}[x]$. Alternatively, $\mathfrak{h}^-$ is the centralizer of
$$f=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{pmatrix}$$
(the "multiplication by $x$" operator).
If we make $\mathfrak{h}^-$ acts on $\Lambda$ by identifying $\mathfrak{h}^-=\mathbb{C}[x]$ as above and letting $p\in \mathbb{C}[x]$ act via multiplication by $p(x_1)+\ldots + p(x_n)$, then it is clear from its construction that the boson-fermion correspondence is $\mathfrak{h}^-$-equivariant.

It is also clear from the definition that the image of the weight basis elements $x^{\lambda_1+n-1}\wedge x^{\lambda_2+n-2}\wedge \cdots \wedge x^{\lambda_n}$ for $\lambda_1 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_n \ge 0$ under the boson-fermion correspondence are the Schur polynomials, defined as

$$s_\lambda = \frac{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) x_{\sigma(1)}^{\lambda_1+n-1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{\lambda_2+n-2}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{\lambda_n}}{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) x_{\sigma(1)}^{n-1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{n-2}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{0}}=\frac{\sum_{\sigma \in S_n} \text{sgn}(\sigma) x_{\sigma(1)}^{\lambda_1+n-1} x_{\sigma(2)}^{\lambda_2+n-2}\cdots x_{\sigma(n)}^{\lambda_n}}{\delta}.$$

To get a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_m$ rather than $\mathfrak{gl}_\infty^+$, we have to take a quotient. Precisely, let $J_m$ be the ideal of $\mathbb{C}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ generated by $x_i^m$ for $i=1, \ldots, n$, $I_m^\text{sgn}=J_m \cap \Lambda_n^\text{sgn}$ and $I_m=\{p \in\Lambda_n\mid \delta p \in I_m^\text{sgn}\}$. Then $I_m$ is spanned by Schur polynomials indexed by partitions with some part larger than $m-n$ and, if we let $\Lambda_{n,m}=\Lambda_n/I_m$, $\Lambda_{n,m}^\text{sgn}=\Lambda_n^\text{sgn}/I^\text{sgn}_m$, then the boson-fermion correspondence induces an isomorphism
$$\bigwedge^n \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^m) = \Lambda_{n,m}^\text{sgn} \underset{\cdot \delta}{\overset{\sim}{\longleftarrow}}\Lambda_{n,m}.$$
The representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_m$ on the left hand side (which comes from identifying $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^m)$ with $\mathbb{C}^m$ via the basis $1,x,\ldots, x^{m-1}$) can therefore be transferred to a representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_m$ on the right hand side.
Moreover, we can define $\mathfrak{h}^-_m$ to be the abelian subalgebra of lower triangular matrices constant on the diagonals. Just as for $\mathfrak{h}^-$, we can identify $\mathfrak{h}^-_m$ with $\mathbb{C}[x]/(x^m)$ and then $p\in \mathbb{C}[x]/(x^m)$ act on $\Lambda_{n,m}$ via multiplication by $p(x_1)+\ldots+p(x_n)$.

We now turn to $H^\bullet(G(n,m))$. The affine Grassmannian $Gr=GL_m(\mathbb{C}(\!(t)\!))/GL_m(\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!])$ can be identified with the set of $\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]$-lattices inside $\mathbb{C}(\!(t)\!)^n$. The $GL_m(\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!])$-orbits are indexed by coweights of $GL_m$ (which are the same as weights because $GL_m$ is self dual) an the geometric Satake correspondence tell us that the intersection cohomology of the closure of the orbit indexed by $\mu$ is isomorphic to the representation of $GL_m$ of highest weight $\mu$. When $\mu=(\underbrace{1, \ldots, 1}_{n}, 0, \ldots, 0)$, the orbit consists of the lattices sandwiched between $\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]^m$ and $t\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]^m$ and of index $n$ inside $\mathbb{C}[\![t]\!]^m$, which is isomorphic to $G(n,m)$. We get therefore that $H^\bullet(G(n,m))$ is isomorphic to the $n^{th}$ wedge representation of $\mathfrak{gl}_m$. The general theory of geometric Satake also tell us that the Schubert cycles form a weight basis for the action of the maximal torus.

Putting all this together, we have an isomorphism of representations of $GL_m$
$$\Lambda_{n,m} \cong H^\bullet(G(n,m))$$
which sends Schur polynomials to Schubert cycles up to scalar since both are weight bases and the weights are multiplicity-free. To see that this is in fact an isomorphism of rings, we can use the action of $\mathfrak{h}_m^-$. We already know that any element of $\mathfrak{h}_m^-$ act on $\Lambda_{n,m}$ by multiplication by some element of $\Lambda_{n,m}$. The corresponding statement is also true for $H^\bullet(G(n,m))$ (this follows from identifying $\mathfrak{h}^-_m$ with the primitive elements in $H^\bullet(Gr)$, as explained in Ginzburg's paper *Perverse sheaves on a loop
group and Langlands’ duality*). Therefore, we have a commutative diagram

[image]

where the two vertical arrows are given by the action on $1$ and are therefore ring homomorphism. Since the left vertical arrow is surjective (as power-sum symmetric functions generate $\Lambda_n$), it follows that $\Lambda_{n,m}\to H^\bullet(G(n,m))$ is itself a ring homomorphisms.

Showing that the scalar by which Schur polynomials and Schubert cycles differ under this isomorphism is actually $1$ is a bit subtle. By working over $\mathbb{Z}$ we can see that it has to be $\pm 1$, and then one can show that it is $1$ by using the structure constants for both bases are nonnegative.

This essentially explains the connection between your points 3 and 4, and we can also easily relate this story to 5 by noting that the wedge representation admits a unique (up to scalar) nondegenerate bilinear form satisfying $(Mv,w)+(v,-M^Tw)=0$ for $M\in \mathfrak{gl}_m$, for which the weight basis is orthonormal (and is the unique orthonormal basis up to signs if we work over $\mathbb{Z}$). The relationship with 2 is essentially Weyl's character formula.